# ConvertBack not been called?

Tags: wpf, binding, converters, dependency-properties, two-way-binding

I have a Grid in ControlTemplate like this

```
 <Grid x:Name="quickMsgGrid" Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsQuickMsg, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}, Mode=TwoWay}">                                    
                                <Border CornerRadius="{Binding ElementName=mainBorder,Path=CornerRadius}" Background="{StaticResource loadingBackgroundBrush}" />
                                <TextBlock x:Name="txtQuickMsg" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">asdfasdfasdfasdf</TextBlock>
                            </Grid>
```

What I am trying is to bind the Visibility to a custom dependency property "IsQuickMsg"

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsQuickMsgProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsQuickMsg", typeof(bool), typeof(baseWindow));

    public bool IsQuickMsg
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsQuickMsgProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsQuickMsgProperty, value); }
    }
```

In this case, when I set IsQuickMsg to true in code-behind, the Visibility of Grid will be set to Visible through converter

```
public class BoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((bool)value ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((Visibility)value == Visibility.Visible);
    }
}
```

Once the Grid is visible, it will begin a storyboard to play some animations then set visibility of Grid to Hidden after finish

```
<Trigger Property="IsQuickMsg" Value="True">                            
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="quickMsgGrid">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="quickMsgGrid" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:2.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="quickMsgGrid" From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:2.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="quickMsgGrid">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Hidden</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>                                    
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
```

However, when the storyboard is end, Grid's visibility been set to hidden, but it doesn't convert the Visibility value back to my custom dependency property "IsQuickMsg"

I set the break point in the ConvertBack function but it never been called.

So what do I do wrong here?

Comment: Post the code that how you are setting it back to `Hidden`? Most likely your binding is broken.

Comment: I set it back to Hidden from storyboard, in a Trigger, please check the Trigger section

Comment: Do you have any binding errors in the Output Window in Visual Studio?

Comment: No, everything works fine without error, when I changed "IsQuickMsg" to true or false in code-behind, the convert function works well, but when the storyboard ends and changed the visibility to hidden, the ConvertBack function never been triggered